# Running multiple versions of Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have an old game made in cocos2d v1, which i have to be able to support and update. But my next game i want to create with cocos2d version 2.
Is it possible to run both versions in one development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Each project can and will use whatever cocos2d version it was created with.

The only thing that's not supported is being able to have multiple Xcode templates of the same cocos2d branch (v1.x & v2.x) installed at the same time. For example you can have the templates for v1.1 and v2.1 installed at the same time, but you can't have v2.0 and v2.1 templates installed at the same time.